# What is this nut on a micrometer head and what is the tool for removing it called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, nomenclature

My apologies for a likely very simple question. But what is this nut which I have on a micrometer head called, and what is the tool for removing it called?

[image: micrometerhead]

Comment: Hmm... the [Starrett 261L](http://www.starrett.com/metrology/product-detail/1-Precision-Measuring-Tools/11-Precision-Hand-Tools/1101-Micrometers/110106-Micrometer-Heads/261L) includes a parts list, and nothing sticks out as having a special name. A "wrench" is mentioned, but couldn't pull up much about it.

Comment: "Round nut" is the best name I can figure out. Google Images search gives some similar results with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short Answer

The nut on it is called a **slotted lock nut** or **locking bearing nut**. You can remove it with a **hook spanner**.

## Long Answer

I guess your micrometer is Japanese and thus probably doesn't conform DIN standards but for slotted lock nuts you can check **DIN 981** or **DIN 1804** and for hook spanner you can check **DIN 1810**

### Why use Lock Nut

The main reason is screw loosening. With time all screws get loose (no pun intended) and on a device such as micrometer that loose fit will cause errors. That nut, locks bearing into place. Below is a similar Lock Nut for bearings from Misumi USA, you can check [datasheet here](http://us.misumi-ec.com/pdf/fa/2012/p1_0917.pdf)
[image: Hard Locking Bearing Nut Misumi USA]

Information about lock nuts and hook spanners from SKF but I don't have enough rep to post more links.

Comment: Welcome to E.SE. Thanks for joining in, that's a wonderful first post and a great answer. I look forward to seeing more from you.